# Where is Android Emulator file structure on macOS?

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, filesystems

Where is *Android Emulator* file structure `(such as /data, /system, etc)` on **macOS?**

It's not under `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-27/google_apis/x86`.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is *Android Emulator* file structure (such as `/data`, `/system` etc) on *Mac OS*?

You cannot **directly** explore *Android Emulator*'s filesystem on *Mac OS*, just because the partitions, `/data`, `/system` etc, aren't mounted on the *Mac OS*'s filesystem.

Your option is [adb shell](http://adbshell.com/).

Comment: How can I mount them on macOS?

Comment: @Aero Wang, a quick search over the Internet brought me [this post](https://solumachines.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/mounting-an-android-system-img-on-mac-os-x/) which is about mounting `system.img` only. You could make a dipper investigation. However, as I mentioned, `adb shell` is one of the most convenient ways to explore _Android_ FS. What is still unclear is your intention. Would you like exploring all the _Android OS_ partitions or just external storage (a.k.a SD card)?

Comment: my intention is to have a shared folder between macOS and Android Emulator.